# Letter by letter Comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sets of data in two cells (A1 and B1) without any special character (.,/;:'"-@#$%^&*(){}[]) and also no space between words,

The problem is I need to compare both the cells and identify and highlight the difference.

For example :

```
(A1): howtobuilfmacroincludingthesecrria
(B1): howbuilfmacroincludingthesecriteria
```

- in A1 `ite` is missing
- and B1 `to` is missing

The macro should highlight `ite` in B1 and `to` in A1

Comment: As an avid and [enthusiast programmer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), what have you done so far? I'm very keen to see your progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the text strings are in cells A1 and B1.

Place these routines in a standard code module (Alt-F11).

Run the FindDistinctSubstrings routine (Alt-F8 from the worksheet).

```
Public Sub FindDistinctSubstrings()
    Dim a$, b$
    a = [a1]
    b = [b1]
    S1inS2 0, 2, a, b, [a1], vbRed
    S1inS2 0, 2, b, a, [b1], vbRed
    S1inS2 1, 3, a, b, [a1], vbBlack
    S1inS2 1, 3, b, a, [b1], vbBlack
End Sub
Private Sub S1inS2(yes&, k&, s1$, s2$, r As Range, color&)
    Dim i&
    For i = 1 To Len(s1)
        If (yes = 0 And 0 = InStr(s2, Mid$(s1, i, k))) Or (yes = 1 And 0 < InStr(s2, Mid$(s1, i, k))) Then
            r.Characters(i, k).Font.color = color
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but is only related the Example but I had different set of sentence Example : A1:ThisisasystemgenerateddocumentandnotrequiresignatureAnyunauthorizedusedisclosuredisseminationorcopyingofthismentisstrictlyprohibitedandmaybeunlawful B1:Thisisasystemgenerateddocumentanddoesnotrequiresignatureunauthorizedusedisclosuredisseminationorcopyingofthisdocumentisstrictlyprohibitedandmaybeunful                                                                                     in this many character missing or added I need to highlight those missing or added character

Comment: Well, that should be a new question then. This question has been answered.

Comment: not new question bro....I need a code that should highlight the missing character as well as new character in one cell if I put different sentence in cells

Comment: This is a difficult problem. You left out this new information in the original question... and this new requirement makes it even much more difficult. I would not have invested the time had you described the full requirements, which absolutely should be a new question.

Comment: could you please help me in this,,,,,,I would be glad

Comment: Sorry, i edited my code, forgot to put code in else staitment. Now it shold work! Can u make an array with this words? Can every word be on secound sheet in separate cells?
For example on sheet2: Column A1 "how"
Column B1 "to" etc and in sheet 1 in cell A1 that cells togeter (A1 + B1)

Answer (score 1):

it's very difficult to perform mutual checks because excel doesn't know the words. What does it words represent? 
You can do check on one column like this:

```
Sub CompareMacro()
Dim columnA As Integer
Dim columnB As Integer
Dim NumberOfCaracters As Integer
Dim f As Integer
f = 1
For numbuerOfRows = 1 To 5
    columnA = Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(numbuerOfRows, 1))
    columnB = Len(Worksheets(1).Cells(numbuerOfRows, 2))

    If columnA > columnB Then
        NumberOfCharacters = columnA
    Else
        NumberOfCaracters = columnB
    End If

    Dim columnALetters(3) As Variant

    For i = 1 To NumberOfCaracters

        If Mid(Worksheets(1).Cells(numbuerOfRows, 1), i, 1) = Mid(Worksheets(1).Cells(numbuerOfRows, 2), f, 1) Then                 
             f = f + 1
         Else
    Worksheets(1).Cells(numbuerOfRows, 1).Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
        End If      
    Next i
Next numbuerOfRows
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but its not working for me, could you please help me to run this macro as I am beginner in macro,,,, grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

You can use object and then use msword concept first A1 content in one and other in second and compare two of them any n no.of words is there it shows and highlight.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).