# Compare (diff) strings in two cells by character

Tags: vba, excel

I have text in two cells with different text. I'm attempting to identify the diff (difference between the text: text that is added or missing) between the two cells

1. In `A1`I have a paragraph of text.
2. `B1` contains a paragraph that is similar, however there are minor differences.

I'm attempting to identify the difference between these strings, please help me to identify those differences in ***both*** cells with color using VBA

Comment: Note that my solution is using A1 and A2 instead of An and B1.

Comment: A duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32296937/compare-text-and-highlight-difference

Comment: @mynameisammu I have reformatted your question to make it more readable as the answer you received was remarkable. For future reference (1) Pls show what attempt you made at answering the question (2) Don't ask duplicate questions (3) Better formatting, choice of title etc can make a difference to how much attention your question gets.

Comment: @brettdj To be fair, I requested him to ask a new question... twice. The reason was because my first answer worked fine for the sample strings he provided, he then followed-up with a much longer pair of strings that completely shot my algo. It seemed that the question was now of a completely different scope and so I asked him to ask a new question since the previous answer worked for the context of that question and had been accepted already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution for your problem and have uploaded a workbook with your sample string pairs. Here is the [workbook](http:///www.excelhero.com/samples/AlignStrings_excelhero.xlsm).

My code is based on the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm), which was first developed in 1970 and is still used today to align DNA sequences in science tech. However I modified the alogrithm and added additional post-processing to work with your sample data string pairs.

Here is how to work the process. Enter your two strings to compare in A1 and A2.

Press Alt-F8 and run the macro, `AlignStrings`.

The results will be displayed in cells A5 and A6.

Note that other sample string pairs can be found further down the sheet, beginning in cell A21.

Here is the code from the workbook that accomplishes the string pair alignment and highlighting of the differences:

```
Public Sub AlignStrings()
    Dim a() As Byte, b() As Byte, a_$, b_$, i&, j&, d&, u&, l&, x&, y&, f&()
    Const GAP = -1
    Const PAD = "_"

    a = [a1].Text: b = [a2].Text
    [a3:a6].Clear
    [a1:a6].Font.Name = "Courier New"

    ReDim f(0 To UBound(b) \ 2 + 1, 0 To UBound(a) \ 2 + 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(f, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(f, 2)
            x = j - 1: y = i - 1
            If a(x * 2) = b(y * 2) Then
                d = 1 + f(y, x)
                u = 0 + f(y, j)
                l = 0 + f(i, x)
            Else
                d = -1 + f(y, x)
                u = GAP + f(y, j)
                l = GAP + f(i, x)
            End If
            f(i, j) = Max(d, u, l)
        Next
    Next

    i = UBound(f, 1): j = UBound(f, 2)
    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        x = j - 1: y = i - 1
        d = f(y, x)
        u = f(y, j)
        l = f(i, x)
        Select Case True
            Case Err
                If y < 0 Then GoTo left Else GoTo up
            Case d >= u And d >= l Or Mid$(a, j, 1) = Mid$(b, i, 1)
diag:
                a_ = Mid$(a, j, 1) & a_
                b_ = Mid$(b, i, 1) & b_
                i = i - 1: j = j - 1
            Case u > l
up:
                a_ = PAD & a_
                b_ = Mid$(b, i, 1) & b_
                i = i - 1
            Case l > u
left:
                a_ = Mid$(a, j, 1) & a_
                b_ = PAD & b_
                j = j - 1
        End Select
    Loop Until i < 1 And j < 1

    DecorateStrings a_, b_, [a5], [a6], PAD

End Sub


Private Function Max(a&, b&, c&) As Long
    Max = a
    If b > a Then Max = b
    If c > b Then Max = c
End Function


Private Sub DecorateStrings(a$, b$, rOutA As Range, rOutB As Range, PAD$)
    Dim i&, j&

    FloatArtifacts a, b, PAD
    FloatArtifacts b, a, PAD

    rOutA = a
    rOutB = b

    For i = 1 To Len(a)
        If Mid$(a, i, 1) <> Mid$(b, i, 1) Then
            If Mid$(a, i, 1) <> PAD Then
                rOutA.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For i = 1 To Len(b)
        If Mid$(a, i, 1) <> Mid$(b, i, 1) Then
            If Mid$(b, i, 1) <> PAD Then
                rOutB.Characters(i, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub FloatArtifacts(s1$, s2$, PAD$)
    Dim c&, k&, i&, p&
    For i = 1 To Len(s1)
        c = InStr(i, s1, PAD)
        If c Then
            k = 0
            Do
                k = k + 1
                If Mid$(s1, c + k, 1) <> PAD Then
                    If Mid$(s2, c, 1) = Mid$(s1, c + k, 1) Then
                        p = InStr(c + k, s1, PAD)
                        If p < (c + k + 6) And p > 0 Then
                            Mid$(s1, c, 1) = Mid$(s1, c + k, 1)
                            Mid$(s1, c + k, 1) = PAD
                            i = c
                            Exit Do
                        Else
                            i = c + k
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Else
                        i = c + k
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
                If c + k > Len(s1) Then Exit Do
            Loop
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am not able to open the work book which you have attached

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: You are welcome. It is a fascinating problem... very challenging. I tried many things and did a lot of research. I ended up making the foundation of the solution based on an algorithm from 1970 called Needleman–Wunsch, which is still used primarily to align DNA sequences in biology. But it was insufficient and I needed to alter it and then further process the results to work with your sample string pairs.

Comment: Really I can't believe its working as per my requirement.....I will never forget this help in my life,,,,,

Comment: @Excel Hero please help in that case

Comment: @Excel Hero if its not work in macro......Please suggest me private HTML format which can identify these differences

Comment: @myNameisAmmu There is no such thing. I don't think you understand just how difficult this problem is. The solution you now have works very well; in fact surprisingly well. The newest example strings you sent my way even demonstrate just how well it works. At the end of those string it is trying very hard (and succeeding) to match as much as possible. Anything beyond this is just heuristics. You want it to make a judgment to forget those single-character matches and just conclude that a large range is not a match, even though there are many matches within it.

Comment: @myNameisAmmu (continuation from the previous message...) If it did that, then many other legitimate discrepancies would be ignored. If a suitable heuristic rule were found for a given pair of strings, it would fail on another pair of strings. Computers do not look at these pairs like we do as humans. The algorithm currently used is perhaps the best that exists for aligning a pair of strings. If you move away from using Word Wrap in the cells and allow the pairs to extend to the right it will be much easier for you to see all of the matching work being done.

Comment: @Excel Hero ok thanks..... I understand how difficult it was, any way thanks a lot for the code its helping me lot