# Excel formula or rules or vba to compare 2 cells and to highlight only the differences

Tags: excel, pandas, vba, google-sheets

Is there any Excel formula or rules or vba to compare 2 cells and to highlight only the differences in another cell or in same cell.

I've two columns column A and column B with each row containing different **text** data in my excel,

Example

Cell A2 contains the text "My name is Bingold Axel"

And cell B2 contains "My name is Axel"

When I type in exact formula in C2 it just returns true or false...

Whereas I want the specific word "Bingold" (as this is the only difference between 2 cells) to be printed on c2 or in the cell A2 the word "Bingold" alone should turn to red font

Any idea how it can be done with excel or do we need pandas?

Comment: This can be done with conditional formatting. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This help document will help you write questions that will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-routine-to-perform-text-diff.714927/ or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32382925/compare-diff-strings-in-two-cells-by-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(SPLIT(A2, " "), NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(B2, " "), SPLIT(A2, " "))))
```

[image]